# Scrapy: Empty response object

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

I hope you are doing great

I am trying to scrape [this website](https://www.tineye.com/search/9fdeed61d697e871c74e38116d9c41276bce052e?page=4&sort=score&order=desc) using the scrapy framework. I just need to output the result titles in a csv file. The task seemed easy at first glance, but when using the scrapy shell, I found that the response object is empty. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the result using the scrapy shell]

I said to myself that this website uses AJAX requests. I took a look on developers tab and found that indeed, the website uses AJAX requests. I reverse-engineered it and found the request url for the AJAX call which is this : https://www.tineye.com/search/get_domains/9fdeed61d697e871c74e38116d9c41276bce052e?

here is an image showing what I did

[image: screenshot of the developers tool tab]

Then I modified my code accordingly, to request the url of the AJAX call, rather than the page itself.

```
import scrapy
import json

#cpt = 0

class SearchSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "search"
    allowed_domains = ["www.tineye.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.tineye.com/search/get_domains/9fdeed61d697e871c74e38116d9c41276bce052e?"]

def parse(self, response):
    #global cpt
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    data = data["domains"]
    for item in data:
        #cpt = cpt + int(item[1])
        yield {
            "link": item[0],
            "times": item[1],
        }
```

But once again, the response object is empty. What should I do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I ran url in scrapy shell and I get page with HTML.

Comment: I ran your spider and get data without problem. Maybe you have different problem with computer.